# Cannot infer functional interface type Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, registry

I have a factory(Registry DP) which initializes the class:

```
public class GenericFactory extends AbstractFactory {

    public GenericPostProcessorFactory() {
        factory.put("Test",
                defaultSupplier(() -> new Test()));
        factory.put("TestWithArgs",
                defaultSupplier(() -> new TestWithArgs(2,4)));
    }

}

interface Validation

Test implements Validation
TestWithArgs implements Validation
```

And in the AbstractFactory

```
 protected Supplier<Validation> defaultSupplier(Class<? extends Validation> validationClass) {
        return () -> {
            try {
                return validationClass.newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unable to create instance of " + validationClass, e);
            }
        };
    }
```

But I keep getting Cannot infer functional interface type Error. What I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: The fact that your lambda throws and doesn't return in every branch may be confusing it. I seem to recall having to write up my own functional interface for this reason.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `defaultSupplier` method has an argument type of `Class`. You can’t pass a lambda expression where a `Class` is expected. But you don’t need that method `defaultSupplier` anyway.

Since `Test` and `TestWithArgs` are a subtypes of `Validation`, the lambda expressions `() -> new Test()` and `() -> new TestWithArgs(2,4)` are already assignable to `Supplier<Validation>` without that method:

```
public class GenericFactory extends AbstractFactory {
    public GenericPostProcessorFactory() {
        factory.put("Test", () -> new Test());
        factory.put("TestWithArgs", () -> new TestWithArgs(2,4));
    }    
}
```

Comment: This is actually is not an "answer". This is rather a "workaround".

Comment: Here TC he has very simple case - what he need is only to create new objects (new Test() and new TestWithArgs(...)).
But consider more complicated case when there are plenty of operations - you could not use this workaround in this case.

Comment: The green checkmarks indicates that the OP agreed that this solved their problem. There is no point in question that more than three years later. Besides that, your objection makes no sense. There is nothing that a `Class.newInstance` could do that a lambda expression couldn’t. In fact, lambda expressions can contain arbitrary Java code, including invocations of arbitrary methods, which can encapsulate operations of arbitrary complexity, so there is no scenario where you can’t use this solution.